# XOR Neural Network using TensorFlow in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, pycharm, xor

I'm currently learning the theory behind Neural Networks, and I want to learn how to code such models. Therefore I've started to look at TensorFlow.

I've found a really interesting application I want to program, but I currently can't make it work, and I don't really know why!

The example comes from [Deep Learning, Goodfellow et al 2016](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/) page 171 - 177.

```
import tensorflow as tf

T = 1.
F = 0.
train_in = [
    [T, T],
    [T, F],
    [F, T],
    [F, F],
]
train_out = [
    [F],
    [T],
    [T],
    [F],
]
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))

w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

out1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(train_in, w1) + b1)
out2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(out1, w2) + b2)

error = tf.subtract(train_out, out2)
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error))

train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(mse)

sess = tf.Session()
tf.global_variables_initializer()

err = 1.0
target = 0.01
epoch = 0
max_epochs = 1000

while err > target and epoch < max_epochs:
    epoch += 1
    err, _ = sess.run([mse, train])

print("epoch:", epoch, "mse:", err)
print("result: ", out2)
```

I get the following error message in Pycharm when running the code:[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLAVc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to *run* the initialization op, you should write:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

Instead of:

```
tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

Here is a working version:

```
import tensorflow as tf

T = 1.
F = 0.
train_in = [
    [T, T],
    [T, F],
    [F, T],
    [F, F],
]
train_out = [
    [F],
    [T],
    [T],
    [F],
]
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))

w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

out1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(train_in, w1) + b1)
out2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(out1, w2) + b2)

error = tf.subtract(train_out, out2)
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error))

train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(mse)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

err = 1.0
target = 0.01
epoch = 0
max_epochs = 1000

while err > target and epoch < max_epochs:
    epoch += 1
    err, _ = sess.run([mse, train])

print("epoch:", epoch, "mse:", err)
print("result: ", out2)
```